# Django, ManyToMany field, get the right object with extra fields

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have 2 models: User and a Car, and I want to create a field for user, which keeps a list of user's cars. I have created 3 classes:

```
class Car():
   type = ...

class User():
   name = ...
   cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car, through='CarList')

class CarList():
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
   car_type = models.ForeignKey(Car)
   extra_field = ...
   extra_field2 = ...
```

Now when I want to get the user's cars, I can use the User.cars.all() "function", which returns the list of all of his cars. Which is all fair and good except it returns a list of foreign keys of Car objects instead of CarList objects (which have extra fields !!)

I know I can use a different query, like: `CarList.objects.get(owner=user, car_type=user.cars.all()[0]), etc...` but this is just inconvenient.

So is there a query which will give me the "CarList" objects ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a User, and you want to get the CarList. Since you have a ForeignKey from CarList to User, that is a simple backwards relation:

```
carlists = user.carlist_set.all()
```

Comment: Yes, this works ! But that would also work without the ManyToMany field with that two tables. I still can't get my head around this Django logic behind it :) Thanks for the help !

Comment: Yes, you're not using the m2m relationship here. That's useful for going directly from User to Car, when you don't care about CarList or its extra fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you only need to do:

```
result = Car.user_set.filter(your_query)
```

Then you can access to the extra fields from result queryset

You can check and better example from Django Docs:

[extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work... Reading the documentation, that section is for Django 1.7, where I am using Django 1.6.5. So is it possible that my idea wont work on Django 1.6 ?

Comment: But that documentation is over there since prior version of Django, is the same. Did u try it ?

Comment: Well, I don't really know how to use that. Let say I querry the User object (lets name the variable user). Then user.cars.all() does not contain any attribute car_set, or user_set... Also the class car does not have attribute user_set (dont know how would that help me anyway).

Comment: Because in Django, it creates a special attribute to allow following backward relationship. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward